# Upgrade VirtualBox from 4.1.2 to 4.1.4

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

I tried to upgrade VirtualBox. Installing VirtualBox is OK but I have a problem with Extension Pack. Here is error.

```
Failed to install the Extension Pack C:/Users/.../Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.1.4-74291.vbox-extpack.

Failed to launch the helper application 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxExtPackHelperApp.exe' (VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR).

Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: ExtPackManager
Interface: IExtPackManager {3295e6ce-b051-47b2-9514-2c588bfe7554}
```

Sidenote: Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open a command prompt as Administrator : Right-click on “Accessories\Command Prompt” and choose : Run As Administrator.
- CD C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
- Make sure the ExtensionPack is located in the same directory
- C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe extpack install Oracle_VM_Virt
  ualBox_Extension_Pack-4.0.4-70112.vbox-extpack

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.0.4-70112.vbox-extpack
0%…10%…20%…30%…40%…50%…60%…70%…80%…90%…100%
Successfully installed “Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack”.

Answer (score 0):

@shaduabhi's suggestion didn't work for me; it just hung. I was experiencing the same error, and fixed it by copying the **Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.1.4-74291.vbox-extpack** file from the network share it was on to a local folder, then opening it.